# How to identify elements within #document

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, iframe

I'm using xpath to scrape information from a dynamic html table. The information I'm trying to scrape is inside of a tag called `#document` and I'm not sure how to include this in the xpath since it doesn't follow the normal `<>...</>` format of most html elements. I also don't have the option to select the xpath when I open the options to the left of the tag in the inspector. What do I do here? I've included a snippet below of the tag I'm referring to.

```
<iframe>
    #document
        <html>...</html>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The *`<html>`* underneth the ***#document*** is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447). To access the elements within that `<html>` you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it* as follows:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"iframe_xpath")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```